# $totalCorrect++ does not work with $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, post, count

i'm trying to generate a score from filling in some quistions of a quiz.
However, i'm using SESSIONS and my score data won't sum up. I'm see a 3 appearing, however there are 6 questions, each good answer is worth 3 points. So with all answers correct, the total score should be 18.

Can some tell me how to fix this?

QUIZ.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["vraag1_antwoorden"] = $_POST["vraag1_antwoorden"];
$_SESSION["vraag2_antwoorden"] = $_POST["vraag2_antwoorden"];
$_SESSION["vraag3_antwoorden"] = $_POST["vraag3_antwoorden"];
$_SESSION["vraag4_antwoorden"] = $_POST["vraag4_antwoorden"];
$_SESSION["vraag5_antwoorden"] = $_POST["vraag5_antwoorden"];
$_SESSION["vraag6_antwoorden"] = $_POST["vraag6_antwoorden"];
?>
```

RESULT.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();


$answer1 = $_SESSION['vraag1_antwoorden'];
$answer2 = $_SESSION['vraag2_antwoorden'];
$answer3 = $_SESSION['vraag3_antwoorden'];
$answer4 = $_SESSION['vraag4_antwoorden'];
$answer5 = $_SESSION['vraag5_antwoorden'];
$answer6 = $_SESSION['vraag6_antwoorden'];

$totalCorrect = 0;

if ($answer1 == "A") { $totalCorrect += 3;}
if ($answer2 == "C") { $totalCorrect += 3;}
if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect += 3;}
if ($answer4 == "C") { $totalCorrect += 3;}
if ($answer5 == "B") { $totalCorrect += 3;}
if ($answer6 == "C") { $totalCorrect += 3;}    

echo $_SESSION['totalcorrect'] = $totalCorrect;

session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: In second code, do `print_r($_SESSION);` and see if your session has right values!?

Comment: may be your condition are evaluating false..

Comment: On which line do I fill: print_r($_SESSION); ??

Comment: Not important, it just should be after `session_start();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to initialize it from the session before you use it (Currently each page starts at 0):

Currently you have:

```
$totalCorrect = 0;
```

But if you use:

```
$totalCorrect = $_SESSION['totalcorrect'];
```

It will carry across the pages.

Finally, echo it out as:

```
echo $totalCorrect;
```

Also, I am unsure why you are even using a session for this variable - it only seems to be used in the final page - so why use a session variable for it at all?